# After updating a dependency to a new version (jfreechart from 1.0.12 to 1.0.13) I get "the type cannot be resolved..." errors

Tags: maven-2, jfreechart

I changed the version from jFreeChart in the pom.xml of my maven project from 1.0.12 to 1.0.13.
Now I get the error
"The type org.jfree.ui.layer cannot be resolved to a type. It is indirectly referenced from required class files."

What does this mean? I just updated the jfreechart dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type is [in the JCommons library](http://www.jfree.org/jcommon/api/org/jfree/ui/Layer.html). I think the problem is that the JFreeChart has not been properly distributed to maven in version 1.0.13. In the [IBiblio directory listing](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/jfree/jfreechart/1.0.13/), you can see that a .pom file is missing (as opposed to [version 1.0.12](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/jfree/jfreechart/1.0.12/), where it's present).

This means that maven has no ideas what the dependencies are. It still downloads the artifact through it's filename by convention, but it doesn't know anything about the context.

Now you can either complain to the vendor and demand a proper pom or create your own pom file (start with [the old version](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/jfree/jfreechart/1.0.12/jfreechart-1.0.12.pom) and adjust it until things start working) and deploy it to your company's repository (or your local repository) using [install:install-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) or [deploy:deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html).

My guess is that you'll at least have to include the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jfree</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.15</version>
</dependency>
```

(If you want to do it the easy way, just add the above dependency to your own project pom)